# How to bring information from one dataframe to another without losing information for duplicates?

Tags: r, dataframe, join, duplicates

Consider df1:

```
id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6); n_df2=c(1,1,2,2,3,3);
df1=as.data.frame(cbind(id,n_df2)); df1
```

where n_df2 is the number of appearances for that id in df2.

```
id2=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,5,6,6);
value=c(25,35,46,78,12,34,12,33,87,56,11,8);
df2=as.data.frame(cbind(id2,value)); df2
```

(id2 is equivalent to id)

I want df1 to look like this:

```
df1$value.1=c(25,35,46,78,12,34) 
df1$value.2=c(NA,NA,12,33,87,11);
df1$value.3=c(NA,NA,NA,NA,56,8); df1;
```

Any help will be very much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In base R you could do:

```
merge(df1, reshape(transform(df2[c('id2','value')],
                   time = ave(id2, id2, FUN = seq_along)),dir = 'wide', idvar = 'id2'),
     by.x = 'id', by.y = 'id2', all.x = TRUE)

  id n_df2 value.1 value.2 value.3
1  1     1      25      NA      NA
2  2     1      35      NA      NA
3  3     2      46      12      NA
4  4     2      78      33      NA
5  5     3      12      87      56
6  6     3      34      11       8
```

In tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    left_join(df2 %>% 
        select(id2, value) %>%
        group_by(id2) %>%
        mutate(time = row_number()) %>% 
        pivot_wider(id2, names_from=time, names_prefix='value.', values_from = 'value'), 
       c('id'='id2'))

     id n_df2 value.1 value.2 value.3
1  1     1      25      NA      NA
2  2     1      35      NA      NA
3  3     2      46      12      NA
4  4     2      78      33      NA
5  5     3      12      87      56
6  6     3      34      11       8
```

Comment: Thank you! just something I forgot to mention, in my real data, df2 has another variabes as well, how can I bring only the value variable?